# Problem when indexing and iterating through dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary, indexing

I am working on building a Vin decoder for a python class, it's going well however I am having an issue when iterating throught a dictionary. Below is all the code I have so far for this project:

```
class vinfo():

    def __init__(self, vin = input("Enter Vin (Without Dashes):")):

        """ Data """
        model_codes = {

        }

        year_codes = {
            "2021":"M","2020":"L","2019":"K",
            "2018":"J","2017":"H","2016":"G",
            "2015":"F","2014":"E","2013":"D",
            "2012":"C","2011":"B","2010":"A",
            "2009":"9","2008":"8","2007":"7",
            "2006":"6","2005":"5","2004":"4",
            "2003":"3","2002":"2","2001":"1",
            "2000":"Y","1999":"X","1998":"W",
            "1997":"V","1996":"T","1995":"S",
            "1994":"R","1993":"P","1992":"N",
            "1991":"M","1990":"L","1989":"K",
            "1988":"J","1987":"H","1986":"G",
            "1985":"F","1984":"E","1983":"D",
            "1982":"C","1981":"B","1980":"A"
        }

        country_codes = {
            "USA":"1", "USA":"4", "USA":"5",
            "USA":"7F","Mexico":"3X", "Mexico":"37",
            "Canada":"3A", "Canada":"3W",
            "Germany":"W", "United Kingdom":"SA",
            "United Kingdom":"SM", "Japan":"J",
            "Korea":"KL", "Korea":"KR"
        }

        engine_codes = {



        }

        if "-" in vin:
            vin = vin.replace("-", "")
        else:
            print("Thanks for entering the Vin without dashes as prompted.")

        if len(vin) == 17:
            self.country_filt = vin[0]
            self.engine_filt = vin[7]
            self.year_filt = vin[9]
            self.manufact_filt = vin[1:3]
            self.serial = vin[-6:]
            self.plant_filt = vin[10]
        else:
            print("You're dumb. Enter a real vin (must be 17 characters).")
        
        self.year = self.find(self.year_filt, year_codes)
        self.country = self.find(self.country_filt, country_codes)
        self.manufact = self.find(self.manufact_filt, model_codes)
        self.engine = self.find(self.engine_filt, engine_codes)

        print(f"You entered: {vin}")
        print(f"Year: {self.year}\nManufacturer: {self.manufact}\nCountry: {self.country}\nEngine: {self.engine}")

    def find(self, filt, dict_of_type_of_codes):
        try:
            key = (list(dict_of_type_of_codes.keys())[list(dict_of_type_of_codes.values()).index(filt)])
        except:
            key = "Not in dict"
        return key

#%% Testing 
# test vin: 48123658489411439
vinfo("48123658489411439")
```

Ideally it would return a print statement that contains the year the car was made and the country it was made in. The year works, but it cannot find the country. 4 is the country code in this example case, and it is clearly USA. Cannot find out why. Ignore the empty dictionaries, I will fill them out once I know that my process works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's one long expression for `key = ...` - did you try to write it out on more than one line? It would make it easier to see where things are going awry. When you used your debugger to evaluate all the expressions in that expression did they all work?

Comment: Why did you make your dictionary backwards? If you want to look up the year for a code wouldn't it be easier if the dictionary was `{code:year,...}`?

Comment: Yeah I tried it before, but i was getting the same error. I found that one line on stack overflow as a solution to a similar problem but it still doesnt work

Comment: If you reverse your dictionary for `country_codes` it will work. Your current structure is `USA: 4` which means if you pass `USA` you get `4`. Since you're currently passing `4`, and that key does not exist, you get nothing.

Comment: Never listen to the person who gave you that line as a way to look up a key in a dictionary. You defeat the _entire_ purpose of having a dictionary by iterating through the values to find the key. Just reverse the dict, and then all you need is `self.year = year_codes[self.year_filt]`, or if you want to avoid a potential KeyError then `self.year = year_codes.get(self.year_filt)`

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: Also note that `def __init__(self, vin = input("Enter Vin (Without Dashes):")):` doesn't do what you expect: default args are evaluated _once, when the function is defined_. If you want to make that arg optional and ask the user for input when it is omitted, you could do `vin = None` and then check `if vin is None: input(...)` inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have duplicating keys in creating your dictionary. Dictionaries are hashmaps that are used by searching for a unique key's corresponding value.

`{"USA": "1", "USA": "4", "USA": "5"}` will only leave you with only one left `{"USA": "5"}`

Secondly, you are doing too much in searching the dictionary which defeats the purpose of using it. E.g. if you are searching for the country based on the code, your dictionary should be the other way around and from there you can simply retrieve the corresponding value (country) for each code:

```
class vinfo:

    def __init__(self, vin = input("Enter Vin (Without Dashes):")):

        """ Data """
        model_codes = {

        }

        year_codes = {
            "M":"2021","L":"2020","K":"2019",
            "J":"2018","H":"2017","G":"2016",
            "F":"2015","E":"2014","D":"2013",
            "C":"2012","B":"2011","A":"2010",
            "9":"2009","8":"2008","7":"2007",
            "6":"2006","5":"2005","4":"2004",
            "3":"2003","2":"2002","1":"2001",
            "Y":"2000","X":"1999","W":"1998",
            "V":"1997","T":"1996","S":"1995",
            "R":"1994","P":"1993","N":"1992",
            "M":"1991","L":"1990","K":"1989",
            "J":"1988","H":"1987","G":"1986",
            "F":"1985","E":"1984","D":"1983",
            "C":"1982","B":"1981","A":"1980"
        }

        country_codes = {
            "1": "USA",
            "4": "USA",
            "5": "USA",
            "7F": "USA",
            "3X": "Mexico",
            "37": "Mexico",
            "3A": "Canada",
            "3W": "Canada",
            "W": "Germany",
            "SA": "United Kingdom",
            "SM": "United Kingdom",
            "J": "Japan",
            "KL": "Korea",
            "KR": "Korea"
        }

        engine_codes = {



        }

        if "-" in vin:
            vin = vin.replace("-", "")
        else:
            print("Thanks for entering the Vin without dashes as prompted.")

        if len(vin) == 17:
            self.country_filt = vin[0]
            self.engine_filt = vin[7]
            self.year_filt = vin[9]
            self.manufact_filt = vin[1:3]
            self.serial = vin[-6:]
            self.plant_filt = vin[10]
        else:
            print("You're dumb. Enter a real vin (must be 17 characters).")
    
        self.year = self.find(self.year_filt, year_codes)
        self.country = self.find(self.country_filt, country_codes)
        self.manufact = self.find(self.manufact_filt, model_codes)
        self.engine = self.find(self.engine_filt, engine_codes)

        print(f"You entered: {vin}")
        print(f"Year: {self.year}\nManufacturer: {self.manufact}\nCountry: {self.country}\nEngine: {self.engine}")

    def find(self, filt, dict_of_type_of_codes):
        return dict_of_type_of_codes.get(filt, 'Not in dict')

#%% Testing 
# test vin: 48123658489411439
vinfo("48123658489411439")
```